# What's the best way to avoid update empty values into mysql from excel userform?

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I'm working in a userform to update a table in mysql and I need to avoid updating if the user try to update with an empty value or update the same value over, I thought to do a verification in the code but it is going to be a long code depending on the size of the table (almost 60 columns at the moment), this is what I would try, any better solution to this?

```
Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    'Connection code to get data from table...

    TextBox1OldValue = rs.Fields("Column1")
    TextBox2OldValue = rs.Fields("Column2")
    ...
End Sub

Sub MySQLTest_Click()

   'Connection code....

    sqlQuery = "UPDATE table SET "

    If TextBox1.Value <> "" And TextBox1.Value <> TextBox1OldValue Then
        sqlQuery = sqlQuery & "Column1='" & TextBox1.Value
    End If

    If TextBox2.Value <> "" And TextBox2.Value <> TextBox2OldValue Then
        sqlQuery = sqlQuery & "', Column2='" & TextBox2.Value
    End If
    ...
End Sub
```

Comment: Obligatory: https://xkcd.com/327/ -- "sanitize your inputs" ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to always send the same statement to the MySQL database, and only changing the parameter values as per user inputs.

The advantage of this, is that a single quote in the textbox isn't going to make the query blow up: this is known as a *SQL injection vulnerability*, and no amount of manual work-arounds are going to patch it. Parameterizing the statement and letting the server deal with the parameter values in a way that's aways going to be more secure than any homegrown client-side solution might achieve. And then the server gets to cache and reuse the execution plan for the next invoke, because it receives the same statement every time.

So the key is to take the "did this value change?" logic server-side... in Structured Query Language - not Visual Basic. We can use the `ifnull` MySQL function in the `WHERE` clause to move the conditional logic out of VBA & the EXCEL.EXE host process... and onto the server:

```vb
'each ? represents an ordinal parameter
Dim sql As String
sql = "UPDATE table AS a " & _
      "SET a.Column1 = ?, " & _
      "    a.Column2 = ? " & _
      "WHERE a.Column1 <> ifnull(?, a.Column1) " & _
      "  OR a.Column2 <> ifnull(?, a.Column2);"
```

We're not going to go and replace these `?` question marks with user inputs. Instead, we're going to create a `Command`, append `Parameter` objects to the command's `Parameters` collection, and then `Execute` the command.

We could do all that inline, but moving it to its own procedure scope feels just right. Something like this:

```vb
'parameters are Variant because other types cannot hold a NULL value.
Private Sub UpdateThing(ByVal conn As ADODB.Connection, ByVal Value1 As Variant, ByVal Value2 As Variant, ByVal Value3 As Variant)

    'local const ensures the string is a compile-time constant:
    '(stops compiling if we attempt to concatenate user inputs)
    Const sql As String = _
        "UPDATE table AS a " & _
        "SET a.Column1 = ?, " & _
        "    a.Column2 = ? " & _
        "WHERE a.Column1 <> ifnull(?, a.Column1) " & _
        "  OR a.Column2 <> ifnull(?, a.Column2);"

    'create a new command
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    
    'wire it up
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandType = adCommandText
    cmd.CommandText = sql
    
    'add the parameter values in the order they must appear in the query.
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(Type:=..., Value:=Value1)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(Type:=..., Value:=Value2)
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter(Type:=..., Value:=Value3)
    
    'run with it
    cmd.Execute
    'Note: Command.Execute method returns a Recordset object. Useful for parameterized SELECT :)

End Sub
```

You'll want the `...` for the `Type` argument to be an ADODB data type that works for the corresponding server-side column value it's used against, and you'll want the `...` for the `Value` argument to probably be a `Variant` local variable or parameter so you can conditionally make it `Null` based on whether a given textbox is empty or contains a value.

Now the client-side decision becomes whether to pass the content of the textbox, or a `null` value.

An even better solution would be to move the SQL string literal out of the code and onto the MySQL server as a *stored procedure* - the `ADODB.Command` would need a few little tweaks, and since a VBA procedure can have up to 40 parameters, for 60 arguments you'll want a `ParamArray` there.

So the call site might look like..

```vb
UpdateThing conn, IIf(TextBox1.Value = "", Null, TextBox1.Value), IIf(TextBox2.Value = "", Null, TextBox2.Value), IIf(TextBox3.Value = "", Null, TextBox3.Value), _
                  IIf(TextBox4.Value = "", Null, TextBox4.Value), IIf(TextBox5.Value = "", Null, TextBox5.Value), IIf(TextBox6.Value = "", Null, TextBox6.Value), ...
```

Now 60 times those... I'd want a function there so I only need to specify `TextBoxN.Value` once, you get the idea. Keep in mind that VBA stops compiling a *logical* line of code that spans more than 20 *physical* lines of code, so you'll want *at least* 3 parameter values per line.

Comment: Thanks! I will try tu use your last sugestion, store the procedure in MySQL, I just started learning about MySQL but I imagine the less information about my database I have in my Workbook/Application makes it less vulnerable to attacks.

Comment: Never the less, it will be an internal application, only people from the place I work will have access to it, and I think the MySQL server only accepts local connection so I believe it should not be a big problem. although I may be wrong

Comment: @GabrielLorscheiter it's not so much about the "attack": SQL injection vulnerabilities are actually bugs.. your program could crash when someone's last name is Null, or when Mr.O'Connor tries to create an account. So many things can go wrong with just normal everyday use, using parameterized commands is going to spare you so many headaches. The huge `Const` string literal could also be loaded from a local `.sql` text file at run-time; that's another way to separate *data* from *code* ;-)